# y = 4; Does &y have a name in the compiler's symbolic table?

Tags: c

I created a snippet of code to test the direct variable and the indirect variable(pointer)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 3;
int y = 4;

int main(void)
{   
    int *pointer;
    *pointer = x;

    printf("x's address is %p, x's value is %d.\n",pointer, *pointer);
    printf("y's address is %p, x's value is %d.\n",&y, y);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
$ ./a.out
x's address is 0x7ffee1b2d6d8, x's value is 3.
y's address is 0x10e0d301c, x's value is 4.
```

I can see that x's address is stored in another memory chunk which is named pointer as a variable in compiler's symbolic table,
How about &y,
y's address could be retrieved by &y which set aside a memory chunk somewhere, Does &y have a name in compiler's symbolic table.

Comment: `*pointer = x;` is invalid. You can't assign a value to `*pointer` unless `pointer` has a valid value first.

Comment: Wouldn't this be an implementation detail of the compiler? I don't see why something like this would be in the language spec.

Comment: pointer is not initialized in your case. Whatever you print is just a trash value. you probably want `int *pointer = &x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the following is not correct:

```
int *pointer;
*pointer = x;
```

`pointer` is uninitialized but you are dereferencing and storing x. You probably meant to assign the address of `x` i.e., `int *pointer = &x;`.

To answer yes, both `x` and `y` are most likely to have separate symbols. You can verify that using tools like `readelf` (on GNU systems):

```
readelf -Ws a.out
```

would display symbols and you can look for `x` and `y`.

Note that details such as symbol and symbol table are outside the scope of C standard (not specified/defined). As such, this could vary across systems.

Besides the standard allows a conforming compiler to generate code as long as the [*observed behaviour*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p6) (also known as the "as-if rule") is respected, meaning "variables" may not always be present in the generated code as compiler might eliminate them (or put them registers) in general.

P.S: In order to print addresses, you need to cast it to `void*` as required by the format specifier `%p`:

```
printf("x's address is %p, x's value is %d.\n", (void*)pointer, *pointer);
printf("y's address is %p, y's value is %d.\n", (void*)&y, y);
```

Comment: I found such the assignment style of `*pointer = 2` in [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Variable-parameters.html#Variable%20parameters)

Comment: The usage in the linked example is quite different: the pointers point to something valid (at the caller), so they can be assigned as such. But your usage is different - contrast with what values the `pointer` has in your example.

Comment: how do you think about ` table = malloc(sizeof *table * count)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `&y` in source code, the compiler does not need to create a new object to store the address of `y`.

The entries in the symbol table are actually the locations of `x` and `y`. (An entry is generally not a complete address but is usually an offset relative to whatever section the symbol is in.)

So, when `&y` is used, the compiler inserts a reference to `y` in the assembly code it generates. The linker and/or loader fills in this reference with the address of `y`.

[The above of course is not part of the C standard. It is only compilers, linkers, and loaders generally work.]